# Logstash 6.5.4 executing bash script in filter ruby plugin

Tags: ruby, bash, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am attempting to execute a bash script using Logstash using filter ruby plugin.

My bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1 log_file="/tmp/test.json"

if [[ -n "$name" ]]; then
    echo "$1=$( date +%s )" >> ${log_file} else
    echo "argument error" fi
```

My Logstash config:

```
input {
  file{
    path => "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    start_position => "beginning"   
    codec => "json"
    type => "json"
    sincedb_write_interval => "1"
    discover_interval => "1"
  }
}

filter {  
  if [host] {
    ruby { code => '
        require "open3"
        host = event.get("host")
        cmd = "/bin/bash /etc/logstash/conf.d/bash_scripts/execute.sh #{host}"
        stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)    '
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "bash_execute"  
  }
}
```

No errors, the events from the file just go and the bash script does not get triggered. I do not really care about any event confirmation or something like that, just want to execute arbitrary bash script that can accept an external argument from the Logstash event.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: This is an old question, but it does pop up in Google. This worked for me: http://vrepin.org/vr/Logstash-filter-external-script/ (basically, the code above is almost there - just need to assign stdout back to the event)